# How do I eliminate my html document's fixed width so that the width varies with the size of the browser window, and the text wraps accordingly?

Tags: html, width, word-wrap

The text in my html document seems to have a fixed width, while I want the width to depend on the size of the user's browser window. If the browser window is small, the text should wrap accordingly, not disappear off the screen. My code used to work fine, but now this problem has developed and I have no idea why. My search for a fix has been futile. I am a complete novice in this area. Most of the explanations I can’t understand. I'm using many of the same html commands that I learned 15 years ago.

This problem applies to the entire document, plain test and tables. Here is a small piece of the code:

```
<font face="lucida handwriting , comic sans ms” color="#990075”> <b>Every</b> 
student is capable of succeeding in mathematics. </font> Confusion can largely 
be attributed to the “one size fits all” teaching methods used in today’s schools.
<u>Individual</u> students require <u>individualized</u> approaches.<br><br>

<font face="lucida handwriting , comic sans ms” color="#990075"> <b>Every</b> 
student can benefit from having a tutor. </font> Whether a student is struggling 
to pass a class or succeeding at an honors level, a tutor provides the opportunity 
to develop a more profound and in-depth understanding of mathematical concepts.<br>
```

I have tried removing all of the styling and have used `<p>` in front of each section, but the same problem persists.

Comment: This (automatic wrapping) should be the default behaviour even today if there is no container that forces a fixed width upon the document.

Answer (score 0):

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Put your text into a div that stretches to 100%, use word-wrap property to make it wrap in the div.